# Class is not mapped

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have problem with configuration of hibernate to get list of all entity from DB. I missing something but have no idea what. Here is my entity and cfg.xml config file: 
I have no problem with insert entity to DB, only problem with get it from DB.
Entity looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    private String name;

    private int age;

    {getters setters}

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", age=" + age + "]";
    }
}
```

and main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("myh2");
        EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        createPerson(entityManager);

        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().
        applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
        SessionFactory factory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());

        Session session = factory.openSession();
        String hql = "select p from " + Person.class.getSimpleName() + " p";
        List<Person> list = (List<Person>) session.createQuery(hql).list();
        System.out.println(list);
        session.close();


        entityManager.close();
        entityManagerFactory.close();
    }
```

hibernate.cfg.xml file looks like this ( i also tried to add mapping class but the same problem also occurs)

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.h2.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:h2:./db/repository</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <!-- <mapping class="second.level.cache.Person"/> -->
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Huh? You create an EntityManagerFactory and then go off and ignore it and use a HIbernate Session?!! (and hardcode use of Hibernate classes) Why not just use an EntityManager and use JPA and dispense with this JPA provider specific code?

Comment: Heh it was stupid ;) thanks for advice. Now its working fine. But i would like to play with second level cache of hibernate and i mix up jpa entityManager with hibernate session. My mistake.